# Views: List content NOT authored by the logged-in user

Tags: views

I want to list all the content that was NOT authored by the logged-in user in Drupal 9.

Getting the list of content authored by the logged-in user is pretty easy.

1. Create a View showing content.
2. Add a required relationship to **Author**.
3. Add a contextual filter **User ID** and set **When the filter value is NOT in the URL** to **Provide default value** *User ID from logged in user*.

But I'm stumped about how to negate this; I want the opposite (all content not created by the logged-in user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contextual filter, scroll all the way down, click on "▾ MORE" and check mark ☑️ Exclude

[image]